# how to apply flat shading for an object with threejs

Tags: three.js

in threejs i want to apply shading for an object, so i had used the below code

```
    <script>

        //initialize viewer mode -- orbit default

        var v_mode='orbit';
        var container, stats;

        var camera, scene, renderer;

        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

        init();
        animate();


        function init() {

            container =  document.getElementById('Viewer');
            document.body.appendChild( container );

         camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
         camera.position.z = 100;

            // scene


            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, container );
            controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 2;
            controls.panSpeed = 2;
            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;
            controls.staticMoving = false;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
            scene.add( ambient );

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
            directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
            scene.add( directionalLight );



            var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl', function ( object ) {

                object.position.y = - 80;
                scene.add( object );

            } );


            //

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );


                // create a camera contol
        cameraControls  = new THREEx.DragPanControls(camera)

        // transparently support window resize
        THREEx.WindowResize.bind(renderer, camera);
        // allow 'p' to make screenshot
        THREEx.Screenshot.bindKey(renderer);
        // allow 'f' to go fullscreen where this feature is supported
        if( THREEx.FullScreen.available() ){
            THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey();        
            //document.getElementById('inlineDoc').innerHTML    += "- <i>f</i> for fullscreen";
        }

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
            mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

            function rotateAroundWorldAxis( object, axis, radians ) {

                var rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

                rotationMatrix.makeRotationAxis( axis.normalize(), radians );
                rotationMatrix.multiplySelf( object.matrix );                       // pre-multiply
                object.matrix = rotationMatrix;
                object.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix( object.matrix );
            }

        }

        function render() {

            var delta = clock.getDelta(),
                time = clock.getElapsedTime() * 5;

            controls.update( delta );

            /*camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;*/

            //camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

            renderer.setClearColor ( 0xFFFFFF, 0.0 );

        }

        function change_Mode(mode)
        {
            //alert(mode);
            if(mode=='fp')
            {

            controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera ); 
            controls.movementSpeed = 70;
            controls.lookSpeed = 0.04;
            controls.noFly = true;
            controls.lookVertical = false;

            }
            else
            {
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, container );
            controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 2;
            controls.panSpeed = 2;
            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;
            controls.staticMoving = false;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
            }
        }

         function wireframe(check){
            // alert(check);
             if(check=='on')
                 {
                      mesh.material.wireframe = true;
                      mesh.material.color = new THREE.Color( 0x6893DE  );
                 }
               else
               {
                   mesh.material.wireframe = false;
                   mesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(0xffffff); 
               }
            }
        var camstart=60;
        function cfv()
        {

         var materials = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial();
         materials.shading = THREE.FlatShading;
          camstart++;
         //alert(start);

         camera.fov = camstart;
         camera.updateProjectionMatrix();


        }


    </script>
```

unfortunately the code doesn't make any sense on my object,

How to apply shade for an object in threejs

Comment: You mean the code doesn't change anything on your object? That seems to be the right code you should post more code, something wrong may be going out outside.

Comment: Hi @mrdoob i have updated the full code, on cfv() i applied shade while click a button, button it doesn't change anything on mode, and am sure i don't have any error on my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh can actually be an entire hierarchy so you need to visit each child of the mesh to change the material. So you need to traverse the mesh and change the material as you visit each child.

```
mesh.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )

        child.material = new material that you want;

} );
```

Comment: Hi @gaitat i have updated the mesh as like var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );scene.add( mesh ); mesh.traverse( function ( child ) {if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh )child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000088 } ; 
} ); but no luck

Comment: That second semicolon from the end should be a paren (ie. `color: 0x000088 } ) });` )

Comment: Actually if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/hJrUR/ you will see that the traverse works as expected. Without the traverse you will get a yellow cube and with the traverse you will get a blue cube.

Comment: No luck man, i want to flat shade for my object which is loaded by OBJMTLLoader

Comment: Created new jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/G8ke6/. The difference between enabling the traverse of the mesh or not should be more visible.

Comment: hi @gaitat, now the shading is working, is this is possible to apply the shading on click some elements ?

Comment: We cannot mix answers of different questions. Please ask another question.